# Is there any way of know if a lambda is running a Retry?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to understand when a lambda function is running a retry. My retries are happening after a timeout or error is thrown. As far as I can tell the context or event doesn't look any different between running a first successful event and retrying.

Ideally, I would be able to do something like:

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
  if (context.retry) {
    ... do something
  }
  ...
}
```

Any ideas are appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order to debug s3 sdk retries, we added logs to them following [How to fetch AWS-SDK retry logs · Issue #2912 · aws/aws-sdk-js](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/2912)

```
AWS.S3.prototype.on('apiCall', console.log);
AWS.S3.prototype.on('apiCallAttempt', console.log);
```

Maybe is something similar to lambdas.

Comment: thanks, was hoping to find something that wouldn't require another service. but looks as though i may have to